# How can I center gallery?

Tags: css, nextgen-gallery

I'd like this gallery at [www.sharminiwijeyesekera.com](http://www.sharminiwijeyesekera.com) to be centered, but right now the thumbnails are `left-aligned`.  Not sure what I'd have to change to have the thumbnails centered on laptop and mobile views.

Comment: you should place portion of your code here. That's how problems are asked and answered. Would you like it if I sent you link to a page where gallery is centered?!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float:left` from `.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box` element and add `display:inline-block` instead. Then on parent `div`, add `text-align: center` to it.

**Updated CSS:**

```
.ngg-galleryoverview {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  display: block !important;
  text-align: center; /* To center */
}


.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box {
  /* float: left; */ 
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```